# Monitor active web connections on IIS 7 in real time (perhaps throttle individual IP's)?

Tags: iis-7, webserver, monitoring, connection

We develop a web app that manages files and resources for different users to download throughout the day on a web server with very limited upstream bandwidth.

Is there any way to monitor in real time how much upstream bandwidth is being taken up by individual connections to IIS (7.0)?

Ideally we'd like way to see a list of each active IIS connection, the KB/s being delivered to each in real time, and the destination IP address.

As a super bonus: Is there any way to individually throttle connections/IP's so that they don't hog all the bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some prosumer-level software firewalls let you do this. If you configure IIS so that each worker process is easily distinguishable from the others, you can accomplish what you want using software like [Net Limiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [Bit Rate Throttling](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/148/bit-rate-throttling-configuration-walkthrough/) module? It can be used to throttle media and non-media files at specified bit rates.